# Как сохранить git hooks во внешний репозиторий

Tags: git, githooks

**git v.1.9.5**

**win xp(x86)**

Подскажите способ сохранить во `внешнем` репозитории хуки написанные в `.git/hooks` в моем `локальном` репозитории.

Необходимо для репозитория-шаблона с которого будет осуществляться создание других репозиториев.

**Вопрос:** есть репозиторий-шаблон на `gitlab`, например, пользователь создает новый на базе шаблона, затем делает себе `git clone` созданного репозитория и получает в нем включенные хуки из репозитория-шаблона, автоматизированно без рук, возможно?

**UPD:** Всегда есть вариант держать в корневой директории репозитория свою папку с хуками и административно заставлять пользователя копировать руками хуки из нее в `.git/hooks`. Но тут возникает проблема аля "я забыл, я не знал, etc..."

**UPD:** вроде бы есть путь через `TEMPLATE DIRECTORY` но если я правильно понял это относиться к созданию нового репозитория локально а не с шаблона на `gitlab`, например, и в итоге хуки будут все равно иметь расширение `sample` и опять необходимо руками убирать это что бы активировать необходимые из них.

**UPD:** может быть есть какая то политика безопасности у `git` из-за которой он принципиально против того что бы без ведома пользователя запускались какие-либо сценарии о которых о может быть не предупрежден? И поэтому хуки всегда надо править ручками...

Comment: Что вам мешает переключиться в `.git/hooks` и сделать там `git init`?

Comment: те сделать в репозитории суб-репозиторий (или что то типа этого)?

Comment: т.е. сделать обычный репозиторий

Comment: Еще можно использовать `git worktree` - но тут надо будет сначала удалить каталог hooks.

Comment: не совсем понял мысль, те если я сделаю в .git/hooks еще один git init и затем выйду на 2 уровня вверх в основной репозиторий и после этого сделаю  add затем commit а затем push все это уйдет во внешний репозиторий и после создания на его базе другого репозитория хуки сохраняться?

Comment: Нет конечно же. Это же два *разных* репозитория.

Comment: тогда как мне это поможет? не совсем понимаю

Comment: вариант с `git worktree` видимо не вариант так как _(C версии 2.5 в Git появились рабочие деревья – worktree)_  а вопрос в рамках `v.1.9.5`

Comment: вроде бы есть путь через `TEMPLATE DIRECTORY` но если я правильно понял это относиться к созданию нового репозитория локально а не с шаблона на `gitlab`, например, и в итоге хуки будут все равно иметь расширение `sample` и опять необходимо руками убирать это что бы активировать необходимые из них.

Comment: Принудительное о-hook-ливание это интересная задача. С меня конкурс, если за пару дней не будет хорошего ответа. )

Comment: А вы с помощью хуков какие проверки осуществляете? На стороне сервера их можно делать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я не специалист и подобная задача у меня впервые, боюсь быть не точным если скажу что знаю как выполнить хуки на стороне сервера, но согласно документации к гиту, есть как клиентские так и серверные. В моем случае клиентских хватает, я прикручиваю свою утилиту которая используя консольный gcomp транспилирует бинарные ert-файлы 1c7.7 в набор подлежащий к diff в виде набора текстовых файлов среди которых есть текстМодуля.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin ага, я вспомнил, вы уже задавали вопрос про клиентские хуки и транспиляцию. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну да, там то все решилось и механизм рабочий, но в итоге возникла эта проблема(надо минимизировать "ручные действия"), возможно придеться и вовсе отказаться от хуков и пойти по пути `Git-атрибутов` https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Настройка-Git-Git-атрибуты

Comment: @NickVolynkin не могли бы вы обратить внимание на ваш личный скайп?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48585/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-vyacheslav-danshin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я и предполагал, есть `политика безопасности`, согласно [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462998/6934016) и коментариев к нему.

> No, putting them into the repository is fine, I’d even suggest doing so (if they are useful for others as well). The user has to explicitly enable them (as you said, for example by symlinking), which is on one hand a bit of a pain, but protects users on the other hand from running arbitrary code without their consent.

Свою задачу я решил другим путем, через IDE, в которой я с помощью скриптов перехватываю событие сохранения бинарника и произвожу необходимые манипуляции с файлом. Хуки мне стали не нужны.

Но если кто то предложит решение вопроса "без рук" и в рамках ОС и версии гит, указанных в вопросе, то возможно это будет интересно тем кто добавил вопрос в избранное и не только.